# Generate certificate with specific OIDs

Tags: xml, openssl, x509certificate

How can I generate self-sign certificate by OpenSSL (or another tool) with specific OIDs.
I tried few solitions from the Internet but it doesn't work. I tried with custom config file, I extended even openssl.cnf but still some errors like "OID already exists" :/

I need to generate self-signed certificate with OID.2.5.4.97 (organization ID) which I need to use later to sign my XML by XAdES.

Anyone can help ?:) Maybe some good tutorial ?

Comment: 'with' this OID where? In the Subject Name? Identifying an extension (it certainly isn't standardized for that)? In the value of an extension, and which, and where? This OID is indeed already defined in OpenSSL with the name **`organizationIdentifier` -- use that name** in the place in the OpenSSL configuration or options that corresponds to where you want it.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Yes, thank you I found it before you answered :) It's exaclty how you said!